# Contact Form 7 Auto responder email not working

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

Hi i have setup Contact Form 7,

It is working fine without Mail2 option.

But it is no working when i enable mail2 option here is settings of mail2 option in screenshot.

[image]

Help me to find out the issue.

Thanks

Comment: in my case i missed the mail required field "mail should be the required field"

Answer (score 0):

Replace "test" with some valid email ID in from field in Mail2.

Comment: yes i tried with that, but its only with yahoo mail

Answer (score 0):

The email may be getting filtered through spam because you have not specified an actual FROM email address in the mail2 option.  Try adding noreply@YOURSITE.com in the FROM field.  Replace 'yoursite.com' with your actual domain name so that the server does not consider it spam.

Comment: yes i tried with that, but its only with yahoo mail

Comment: what is only with yahoo mail?